# plpython, no such directory error in postgresql (ubuntu)

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu-12.04, plpython

I installed the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython-8.4
```

But while using:

```
user=# create language plpythonu;
```

Error is thrown:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
```

What am  I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using psql 9.1 and was installing postgresql-plpython-8.4. 
Should have run this:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython-9.1
```